# Adding new page to ASP site

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I do apologise if this is a really daft question. I am wanting to add a simple page to an existing ASP site. Being a complete newbie to asp as I usually work in HTML / PHP I am really struggling. 
By my research so far I am needing to download Visual Studio right? Is there an alternative? Can I not just use a text editor (Sublime is my usual) and upload via Filezilla?

- Edit* I would like to add, the website I am wanting to add the new page to is part of a restrictive CMS that will not allow me to add a Javascript contact form via the WYSIWYG

Any light on this matter would be extremely valued

Regards

Comment: Just to clarify, we're talking about a new ASPX page?

Comment: @Blachshma yes, on the site. It is part of a CMS that is vwery restrictive on the back end and I need to add a new page that includes Javascript. The WYSIWYG won't allow it so I am hard coding it in the new page's template

Answer (score 0):

You can use text Editor and save file with extension aspx and copy it in to your project Or simply open your project in Visual studio and add new web form in it.

Comment: Just did this and it showed a page with ' Server Error in '/' Application.'

Comment: Which method you use? Text Editor or Visual studio

Comment: Sublime Text 2 and Filezilla. I duplicated an existing page and edited the content, called it another name and uploaded it

Comment: First you run your application on local machine and notice any error. If it is running successfully then upload to server.